# Rewrite CListBox as a CCheckListBox

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc, clistbox

I am working on a Windows application using MFC and Visual Studio C++ 17.
I have multiple tabs in the application, one of which is currently implemented using `CListBox` and needs to be reimplemented using `CCheckListBox`.
[`CCheckListBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cchecklistbox-class?view=msvc-170) is a child class of [`CListBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/clistbox-class?view=msvc-170).

I have a vector of unique `CString`'s I want to display in the box.
To start simple, I tried making the tab with `CListBox` and by using `CListBox::AddString()`, this worked exactly as I wanted it to. It sorted the strings alphabetically, and automatically added a scroll bar on the side when the vector had too many `CString`'s to display all at once in the list.

However, when swapping the `CListBox` variable to a `CCheckListBox` variable, I have come across the error when I press run along the lines of:

> `Debug Assertion Failed! ..... \mfc\winctrl3.cpp Line: 588`

I found this [GitHub link](https://github.com/Rupan/winscp/blob/master/libs/mfc/source/winctrl3.cpp) that has the `winctrl3.cpp` file and on line `588`, there is a function called `OnLButtonDblClk` which is somewhat explained [here](http://www.icodeguru.com/VC&MFC/MFCReference/html/_mfc_cwnd.3a3a.onlbuttondblclk.htm).

The trouble is I am unsure of how to swap a variable from a parent class to a child class. Is it so different for Windows classes? In the courses and programs I have taken and written in the past, switching from a parent to child variable was straightforward but this is quite the opposite !

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance ! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no assertion in line 588 of the source file in your link. That github upload dates back to 2014. Why not search the winctrl3.cpp source file in your own Visual Studio installation instead? In my own installation, it is in function `PreSubclassWindow()` and there is indeed an assertion there:

```
    // CCheckListBoxes must be owner drawn
    ASSERT(GetStyle() & (LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED | LBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE));
```

That is the `CCheckListBox` must be owner-drawn. Find the `CCheckListBox` constructor code above, you will notice that it calls the `CListBox` (parent-class) constructor, applying either of the two owner-drawn styles. Instead, the `CListBox` constructor calls `CWnd::Create()` with the `"LISTBOX"` Windows Class-Name as a parameter. That is, it seems  to be a MFC-implemented control, overriding the `CListBox` class, with an owner-drawn style. There is no mention of a native "Check-ListBox" class or style in the Win32 documentation either. Also the `CCheckListBox` documentation (in the link you posted) clearly states: *`CCheckListBox` is only for owner-drawn controls because the list contains more than text strings.*

Therefore:

- If you are creating the control using a resource script, add an owner-drawn style (eg `LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED`) to the control (or set the Owner-Drawn property in the property editor).
- If you are creating the control programmatically make sure you are calling the `CCheckListBox` constructor, not the `CListBox` one.

Not sure what you mean about the scroll-bar (and why you mention it), doesn't the list-box display a scroll-bar automatically (`WS_VSCROLL` style - or property), do you have to do something on your own?

---

**EDIT:**

Forgot to mention, if you are creating the control using a resource script use the Class Wizard to add a member variable (of "Control" type, not "Value") to the dialog class. The new variable must be of type `CCheckListBox` (MFC class). This will subclass the control. If the old project already had a `CListBox` member variable change it to `CCheckListBox`.

Comment: Where did you find the winctrl3.cpp file ? This is my first time working with MFC and I have looked online and searched my computer but I cannot find where it is stored

Comment: Is this a valid control in the resource script ? `LISTBOX         IDC_LIST1,303,22,278,218,LBS_SORT | LBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE | LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP` IDC_LIST1 is a value defined in the resource.h file, the 4 numbers state the position of the box, and the rest are styles; when adding the LBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE you mentioned, it gave me a fresh error from winctrol1 or 3.cpp for both a CListBox or CCheckListBox variable

Comment: The MFC source files are located under the C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\atlmfc\src\mfc folder. I can't remember where I got them from, I think they were installed during the initial installation. You can check the Visual Studio Installer (if you manage to run it, it's problematic) and see if they are available as options. Otherwise please try a Microsoft forum.

Comment: Why have a `LBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE` list-box? This means that its items can have a variable height, and you have to override MeasureItem(), that is tell the system what's each item's height every time you are asked - you have to override DrawItem() too. The CCheckListBox implementation as is works for `LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED` list-boxes (fixed item height) and its DrawItem() implementation draws the check-box and the text. You must check the Has Strings style too. The No Data style must NOT be set, it stores the checked/unchecked state data there (in the items' "data").